# website gives error 403 even have 755 permission

Tags: apache

I created a new virtual host on a VPS. i already point the domain to the server IP address. when I access the website it's gives me error 403 even the public_html has `755` file permission. what could be the problem?

[image]

EDIT: i found the following error log.

```
cannot server directory /home/batiktridaya/public_html: No matching directory (index.html, index.html, index.php, index.php4, index.php5) found, and server generated directory index forbidden by Options directive.
```

Comment: Have you read the full error message yet?

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions of the files within public_html, also what user is apache running as?